# How to separate data between Symfony2 environments?

Tags: database-design, symfony, doctrine

Here is the scenario:

We are wanting to build a Symfony2 app which we will host different clients on. Instead of having one environment (let's say the de-facto "prod" environment), each client is getting their own environment.

So, let's say we have clients "foo" and "bar". We would then have like three environments: one for "foo", one for "bar", and then one for our development use (let's call it "dev"). While I am only giving this example, let's say we can have in the tens to the hundreds of clients.

The point of this is that we want to separate the data for the clients. Our app will work the same among all of our clients (same bundles, etc.), however, they each have their own data and it really should not be accessible by the other clients (this gives them data security and makes it easier for us to backup, restore, import and export data for each client). We already have the method to allow this kind of functionality (one client per environment), however, when it comes to storing database data, we believe we will be having some trouble.

I'm assuming, from what I have read in the documentation, that a Symfony2 environment really just allows you to load different config files (unless other alterations are made). So, I'm also assuming that if in these config files, they all point to the same database config, that the environments would "share" the database. More or less, whatever somebody inputs in environment "foo" is just as accessible when in environment "bar". This is not desired.

Using this notion of environments out-of-the box, I see three choices:

1. Give each client their own database server. This will provide maximum performance and will separate data. It would also be easy to get this information into the config files. However, it is expensive and hard to maintain.
2. Use one database server, but give each their own schema. This separates data and is most cost-efficient, however, I am sure there performance issues that will eventually popup (as the schema count gets to be rather large), and it would still be hard to maintain (like when having to update a table structure).
3. Throw all the information into one database and one schema, however, use some sort of application logic to differentiate it. While this is plausible (this is what we currently do in our legacy app; tie everything to a client PKID), I'm not too sure how easy this would be with using the ORM, which we would like to use...

Personally, I'm kind of torn between the third option (one db, one schema, and filtering by application logic) and a hybrid of the first and second (give each client their own schema and provision new servers and move people around once performance issues show up). I believe my hybrid of 1 and 2 would be the easiest, as it simply would need to change config options (point an environment to a server and a schema). But, I think that option 3 would be the best performance-wise, it just may be harder to setup, if even possible.

So, what I am wanting to know is if there is a way to accomplish this via the third option (using application logic to separate the data)? I'm really looking for an "easy" solution. By "easy", I mean using the tools and features already built into Symfony2 or Doctrine, such as maybe a doctrine config setting or even something as writing a Doctrine extension that somehow records the environment for a piece of data and links it to it.

Or, if anyone has other suggestions, I would be interested in hearing them as well.

We anticipate using MySQL for the database. This app will run on Linux VMs with Apache and PHP installed.  We will also be using the most current release of Symfony2.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to first state that environments in symfony are not to differ between clients but between dev/test/staging/prod. I don't know a use case from the top of my head where your way of using environments will cause problems, but working against the framework is usually a bad idea.

I of course don't know everything about your project, but it seems to me that you have the very common usecase of different "users" (you call them clients) accessing your project and need to see different data while having different "settings" (which you call configuration).

But if this is the way you decided to structure your application, let's work with it. Your solution points 1 and 2 are the same for symfony. Symfony doesn't care if the dbms is on a different server or if 100 databases are running on the server. It just needs a host and the correct credentials. So you could start with 1 database server and if you see performance decrease you could add a second one.

This solution, however, is of course critical when facing updates. You deploy your application and have to update 100 databases. As you cannot deploy for only one client, you either take down the whole application till database migration is finished or you develop your application with backwards compability. This might work but it tends to get ugly when the third workaround for a poor decision regarding schema layout is needed.

Your third solution would be the classical approach. Depending on security risks, you would add another layer between the application and doctrine which alters the queries in a way that only data for the particular client can be accessed.

I would go for option three. If you think you might have performance issues, you might want to think about scaling techniques, especially as this tends to be not that easy with MySQL (or any RDBMS).

Comment: Thanks for the response. You mentioned "adding another layer between the application and Doctrine"... Is this more or less going to be some sort of a "hack" that doesn't really work into the rest of the framework, or is there some built in feature of Symfony2/Doctrine that you can point me towards that would allow for this?

Comment: Actually, there are some ways. Doctrine has ACL support, which could be used but as it involves additional tables and therefor additional queries to see if a certain client can access a certain object. You can of course just implement your own "acl", for example by creating something on top of the repository which gets asked for an object and does some checks if the client is allowed to show the object before returning it.

Comment: Curious, but could this be of use to me? I'm wondering if I could use a Doctrine filter to add another condition to each query where some table column is equal to the environment name... http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/filters.html

Answer (score 0):

Due to our resources (we couldn't afford it and are wanting to use MySQL), this is not really an option for us, but would like to mention it as I find it very interesting and it would solve our problem right at the database level.

Oracle Database (the Enterprise Edition I believe) has a feature called "Virtual Private Database" which does exactly what we need.  Basically, you can add access policies to the tables, rows, or even columns right within the SQL engine based on the user connecting to the database.  This way, the data can live all in the same table, but you can use the SQL engine to automatically hide and prevent access to data rows/columns that the user shouldn't be able to see.

This seems like an awesome feature, but licensing requirements and other costs would prevent us (and probably a lot of people) from being able to use this...

[Virtual Private Database](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/security/index-088277.html)

[Using Oracle Virtual Private Database to Control Data Access](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/network.111/b28531/vpd.htm)